# Aptana Studio syntax coloring for PHP

Tags: php, aptana, syntax-highlighting, aptana3

I have a web server that is configured to parse .pg files as php (don't ask :)). I'm using Aptana configured for FTP to edit the files on it and when they were PHP files, the syntax highlighting worked fine. Now that they're .pg files, the syntax highlighting is broken. Can I configure Aptana to use PHP syntax treatment on .pg files?

Comment: Did you check Aptana, Eclipse documentation ?

Comment: Yes you can in the preference menu (which would be the first location I would check btw).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to "Preferences", then you have to select at the left site "General" -> "Editors" -> "File Associations". There you can add file-formats on the right site. In your case you add "*.pg" and select below "PHP Source Editor" (with "add" button")